# undefined method ... for class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I'm just startin to learn ruby and I'm writing a simple program, but I've got an error `undefined method 'send_for_beer' for Person:Class (NoMethodError)`
Here is a code:

```
class Person
    @iq = 0
    @speed = 0
    @power = 0
    @beauty = 0
    def initialize (iq, speed, power, beauty)
        @iq = iq
        @speed = speed
        @power = power
    end

    def send_for_beer
        result @iq * 2 + @speed * 10 + @power * 5 + @beauty
        return result
    end
end

number_of_people = 3
person_array = Array.new(number_of_people, Person)
n = 0
beer_person = 0
beer_cof = 0
number_of_people.times do 

    ............
    person_array.push(Person.new(iq, speed, power, beauty))

    if person_array[n].send_for_beer > beer_cof     <-----here is an error
        beer_cof = person_array[n].send_for_beer
        beer_person = n
    end
    n = n+1
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
person_array = Array.new(number_of_people, Person)
```

In short, don't make array like this.  Use the `[]` literal syntax.  What this returns is:

```
[Person, Person, Person]
```

That is 3 references to the `Person` class, not instances.  Then later you do:

```
person_array.push(Person.new(iq, speed, power, beauty))
```

And you end up with:

```
[Person, Person, Person, person_instance]
```

So when you iterate through and call `send_for_beer` on that first item, it does have that method because `send_for_beer` is an instance method that you are calling erroneously on a class object.

The fix here is to simply assign `person_array` to an empty array literal, and then push things to it.

```
person_array = []
```

---

And a minor style note: `<<` is usually preferred to `Array#push`, making the filling of the array look more like this.

```
person_array << Person.new(iq, speed, power, beauty)
```

---

Ruby also support implicit return of the last expression in a method.  So you do not need to `return result`.  Instead, simply calulate the return value as the only line in the method.

```
def send_for_beer
  @iq * 2 + @speed * 10 + @power * 5 + @beauty
end
```

---

Instance variables don't quite work like that either.  When you have `@name` in the class body directly, you are not initializing instance variables for each instance.  You are actually setting instance variable on the class object (which is weird, I know).  What you actually need to do is set them from any instance method, typically `initialize`, which you are doing here.  So you can totally remove the instance variable setting at the class level here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've a syntax error in the method `send_for_beer` , the `=` sign is missing in the affectation of the variable `result`.

By the way, the method can be written

```
def send_for_beer
    @iq * 2 + @speed * 10 + @power * 5 + @beauty
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of fixed length, you can supply a block to create a new Person object for each element.  You could rewrite your person_array line as follows:

```
person_array = Array.new(number_of_people) { Person.new(0, 0, 0, 0) }
```

Add the following line to the top of your class.

```
attr_writer(:iq, :speed, :power, :beauty)
```

This snipped of code could then modify the objects in your array.

```
person_array.each do |p|
    p.iq, p.speed, p.power, p.beauty = rand(20) + 1, rand(5) + 1, 1
    p.beauty = 10 if (rand(2) == 0)
end
```